# Want to use inner element sum in case condition in N1QL couchbase

Tags: couchbase, sql++

I want to run like below query

```
    SELECT round(sum (ARRAY_SUM(case when ANY x IN transactions SATISFIES 
x.type` `in [0,4] then transactions[*].amount else 0 end))),2) 
total_income,_type`     `FROM mybucket WHERE _type='Company'
```

I have multiple json like below

```
    {
  "_type": "Company",
  "created": "2015-12-01T18:30:00.000Z",
  "transactions": [
    {
      "amount": "96.5",
      "date": "2016-01-03T18:30:00.000Z",
      "type": 0
    },
    {
      "amount": "483.7",
      "date": "2016-01-10T18:30:00.000Z",
      "type": 0
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to sum of transactions->amount which has type in [0,1] I want it in case condition. How can I do it ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT CASE WHEN array_count(a) > 0 THEN ARRAY_SUM(a) ELSE 0 END
FROM default
LET a = ARRAY TONUMBER(x.amount) FOR x in transactions WHEN x.type IN [0,4] END
WHERE _type = "Company";
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. **Flaggers / reviewers:** [For code-only answers such as this one, downvote, don't delete!](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260413/2747593)

Answer (score 0):

btw, you can write this query using different language constructs in N1QL. Check [UNNEST](http://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/4.5/n1ql/n1ql-language-reference/from.html#story-h2-4), and [array-indexing](http://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/4.5/n1ql/n1ql-language-reference/indexing-arrays.html). Especially, when you have filters on array elements (such as transactions[*].type), you can leverage array indexing for better perf and pushdown any filtering to where clause (and indexes).